# How to remove multiply-defined label in pgfplotstable using longtable

Tags: cross-referencing, longtable, pgfplotstable, labels

I need to add caption to a `longtable` possibly with a label to reference in text, however SIAM format fails when it encounters multiply-defined labels because of the repeated caption. Is there an easy way to add label to the first caption?

Here is MWE. First compilation is OK, however second compilation gives this error:

```
! SIAM Label Error: There were multiply-defined labels. Correct multiply-defined labels.
```

Required files, siamltex.sty, siamltex.cls, siamltex.clo, and siam10.clo can be downloaded from: http://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php

```
\documentclass[final]{siamltex}
%\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
Idx  Nam Dim Grd
1   Ady 53  F
2   Bar 72  C
3   Cor 83  B
4   Dar 58  D
5   Esa 68  C
6   Foo 67  C
7   Gar 74  C
8   Hur 65  D
9   Jaz 85  B
10  Ker 91  A
1   Ady 53  F
2   Bar 72  C
3   Cor 83  B
4   Dar 58  D
5   Esa 68  C
6   Foo 67  C
7   Gar 74  C
8   Hur 65  D
9   Jaz 85  B
10  Ker 91  A
1   Ady 53  F
2   Bar 72  C
3   Cor 83  B
4   Dar 58  D
5   Esa 68  C
6   Foo 67  C
7   Gar 74  C
8   Hur 65  D
9   Jaz 85  B
10  Ker 91  A
1   Ady 53  F
2   Bar 72  C
3   Cor 83  B
4   Dar 58  D
5   Esa 68  C
6   Foo 67  C
7   Gar 74  C
8   Hur 65  D
9   Jaz 85  B
10  Ker 91  A
1   Ady 53  F
2   Bar 72  C
3   Cor 83  B
4   Dar 58  D
5   Esa 68  C
6   Foo 67  C
7   Gar 74  C
8   Hur 65  D
9   Jaz 85  B
10  Ker 91  A
1   Ady 53  F
2   Bar 72  C
3   Cor 83  B
4   Dar 58  D
5   Esa 68  C
6   Foo 67  C
7   Gar 74  C
8   Hur 65  D
9   Jaz 85  B
10  Ker 91  A
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableset{
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},}
I am referencing to the long table~\ref{aLabel}.
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,header=true,    
columns={Idx,Nam,Dim,Grd},      % display specified columns
columns/Idx/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0,column type=r},
columns/Nam/.style={column type=l,string type},
columns/Dim/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,column type=r},
columns/Grd/.style={column type=l,string type},every head row/.style={before row={\caption{A caption}\label{aLabel}\\\toprule}, after row=\midrule\endhead}, every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}]{testdata.dat}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`longtable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) allows the specification of `\endfirsthead` and `\endhead`. The usage of these commands you shown in the documentation of [`pgfplotstable` at page 21](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) as well.

Here the modification:

```
\makeatletter
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,header=true,    
columns={Idx,Nam,Dim,Grd},      % display specified columns
columns/Idx/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0,column type=r},
columns/Nam/.style={column type=l,string type},
columns/Dim/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,column type=r},
columns/Grd/.style={column type=l,string type},%
every head row/.append style={%
    typeset cell/.code={%
       \ifnum\c@pgfplotstable@colindex=1\relax
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{
                             \caption{A caption}\label{aLabel}\\\toprule ##1 \gdef\@tempa{\caption*{A caption}\\\toprule ##1&} &}%
       \else
        \ifnum\c@pgfplotstable@colindex=\c@pgfplotstable@numcols\relax
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{##1\g@addto@macro\@tempa{ ##1\\\midrule\endhead}\\\midrule\endfirsthead\@tempa}%
                        \@tempa
        \else
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{##1\g@addto@macro\@tempa{ ##1&} & }%
        \fi
           \fi
    },
},
 every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
]{testdata.dat}
\makeatother
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
Idx  Nam Dim Grd
1   Ady 53  F
2   Bar 72  C
3   Cor 83  B
4   Dar 58  D
5   Esa 68  C
6   Foo 67  C
7   Gar 74  C
8   Hur 65  D
9   Jaz 85  B
10  Ker 91  A
1   Ady 53  F
2   Bar 72  C
3   Cor 83  B
4   Dar 58  D
5   Esa 68  C
6   Foo 67  C
7   Gar 74  C
8   Hur 65  D
9   Jaz 85  B
10  Ker 91  A
1   Ady 53  F
2   Bar 72  C
3   Cor 83  B
4   Dar 58  D
5   Esa 68  C
6   Foo 67  C
7   Gar 74  C
8   Hur 65  D
9   Jaz 85  B
10  Ker 91  A
1   Ady 53  F
2   Bar 72  C
3   Cor 83  B
4   Dar 58  D
5   Esa 68  C
6   Foo 67  C
7   Gar 74  C
8   Hur 65  D
9   Jaz 85  B
10  Ker 91  A
1   Ady 53  F
2   Bar 72  C
3   Cor 83  B
4   Dar 58  D
5   Esa 68  C
6   Foo 67  C
7   Gar 74  C
8   Hur 65  D
9   Jaz 85  B
10  Ker 91  A
1   Ady 53  F
2   Bar 72  C
3   Cor 83  B
4   Dar 58  D
5   Esa 68  C
6   Foo 67  C
7   Gar 74  C
8   Hur 65  D
9   Jaz 85  B
10  Ker 91  A
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableset{
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},}
I am referencing to the long table~\ref{aLabel}.
\makeatletter
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,header=true,    
columns={Idx,Nam,Dim,Grd},      % display specified columns
columns/Idx/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0,column type=r},
columns/Nam/.style={column type=l,string type},
columns/Dim/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,column type=r},
columns/Grd/.style={column type=l,string type},%
every head row/.append style={%
    typeset cell/.code={%
       \ifnum\c@pgfplotstable@colindex=1\relax
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{
                             \caption{A caption}\label{aLabel}\\\toprule ##1 \gdef\@tempa{\caption*{A caption}\\\toprule ##1&} &}%
       \else
        \ifnum\c@pgfplotstable@colindex=\c@pgfplotstable@numcols\relax
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{##1\g@addto@macro\@tempa{ ##1\\\midrule\endhead}\\\midrule\endfirsthead\@tempa}%
                        \@tempa
        \else
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{##1\g@addto@macro\@tempa{ ##1&} & }%
        \fi
           \fi
    },
},
 every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
]{testdata.dat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @MarcoDaniel, thanks for the solution of using `\endfirsthead` and `\endhead`. However, this solution does not work correctly. I have encountered several problems: Caption is put below row headers, row headers vanish. In my original code, there are three lines of multi-column header. I have also examined the sample in the pgfplotstable, but no hope.

Comment: @Kadir: Fixed it.

Comment: Dear @MarcoDaniel, very very thanks for the solution.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel, this is a very nice sollution, with just one little drawback for me: the content of `\@tempa` gets printed into my document, do you have any idea how to prevent that?